# Basic while loop to scanf an integer

Tags: c, stdio

I'm trying to create a C program to allow the user to input an integer number greater than 0, but if any other type is entered make the user try again until they enter an integer.

```
int minBet;

printf("Enter integer"\n);

while(scanf("%d",&minBet)!=1)
{
    printf("Must be an integer value greater than 0\n");
    scanf(" %d",&minBet);
}
```

When a non integer value is entered the printf statements loops infinitely. How can I solve this?

**can only use stdio.h and NO global varables**

Comment: hint use `break` keyword and only *one* scanf;

Comment: also you should post code such that someone else can simply compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input character doesn’t match the coversion, it’s left in the input stream to foul up the next read - you’ll have to get rid of it using `getchar` or `fgetc`.

```
while ( scanf( “%d”, &minBet ) < 1 )
{
  getchar();
  printf( “You entered a non-numeric value, try again: );
}
```

Comment: Asher remember this is a hint, what happens to the prompt, if user puts in `abcd` as bet?

Answer (score 0):

When you type let's say *e*, you type *e* and then press the ENTER key. So there are now 2 characters in the input buffer. `scanf("%d")` reads the *e* , but the newline character is still in the input buffer.

A simpler solution to your immediate problem is to add a `getchar()` after each `scanf("%d")`. This code will work .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int minBet;

printf("Enter integer \n");

while(scanf("%d",&minBet)!=1)
{
    getchar(); 
    printf("Must be an integer value greater than 0\n");
}
}
```

Additionally your code `printf("Enter integer"\n);` is wrong.It should be

```
printf("Enter integer \n");
```